# Use react to focus input element with caret/text-cursor at end of text using onKeyDown

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input

I have two input fields in my component:

```
const MyComponent = () => {

  const onKeyDown = (event: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    if (event.key === 'ArrowLeft') {
      ref.current?.setSelectionRange(value.length, value.length)
      ref.current?.focus()
    }
  }

  const [value, setValue] = useState('1234')
  const ref = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null)

  return (
    <>
      <input
        onChange={({target}) => setValue(target.value)}
        value={value}
        ref={ref}
        type={'text'}/>

      <input
        onKeyDown={onKeyDown}
        type={'text'}/>
    </>
  )
}
```

---

When i hit the left arrow-key on the second input, the first input should be focused, and the cursor should be at the end of the input text.

But the cursor is at the wrong place. Why is this not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was the cursor moving one position to the left of the last character?

Interestingly, when using `onKeyUp` (the release of the key) rather than `onKeyDown` the issue seems to go away. I've listed that solution followed by a couple other examples with explanations below.

### Solution

```
import { useRef, useState } from "react";

const MyComponent = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("1234");
  const ref = useRef(null);

  const onKeyUp = (event) => {
    if (event.key === "ArrowLeft") {
      const textInput = ref.current;
      const len = value.length;

      textInput.setSelectionRange(len, len);
      textInput.focus();
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <input
        onChange={({ target }) => setValue(target.value)}
        value={value}
        ref={ref}
        type={"text"}
      />

      <input onKeyUp={onKeyUp} type={"text"} />
    </>
  );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/cursor-end-of-input-onkeyup-x6ekke

### Explanation

My guess is that because `onKeyUp` naturally follows `onKeyDown`, when we receive the `onKeyDown` event in React, per your example code, the following sequence occurs (or generally speaking something like this is happening):

Inside `onKeyDown`...

1. Our cursor is moved to the very end of the text input.

   ref.current?.setSelectionRange(value.length, value.length)
2. The text input receives focus.

   ref.current?.focus()
3. Then, the release of the left arrow key causes `onKeyUp` event to run in the DOM (we haven't done anything to handle this in React) while *the focus is now on the text input* as a result of step 2 above. The default behavior pressing/releasing the left arrow key while the input has focus is to move the cursor one position to the left, placing it one position from the end of the input text.

### Other Examples/Solutions

If you stick with the use of `onKeyDown`, here are a couple other examples.

#### event.preventDefault()

```
const onKeyDown = (event) => {
  if (event.key === "ArrowLeft") {
    event.preventDefault();
    const textInput = ref.current;
    const len = value.length;
    textInput.setSelectionRange(len, len);
    textInput.focus();
  }
};
```

#### setTimeout()

```
const onKeyDown = (event) => {
  if (event.key === "ArrowLeft") {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const textInput = ref.current;
      const len = value.length;
      textInput.setSelectionRange(len, len);
      textInput.focus();
    }, 0);
  }
};
```

[https://codesandbox.io/s/cursor-end-of-input-example-h1yrdr](https://codesandbox.io/s/cursor-end-of-input-example-h1yrdr?file=/src/App.js)

My guess is that these workarounds effectively block the browser from firing the native key down and up events altogether or delay our handler from running until *after* the native events have fired, respectively.

Comment: event.preventDefault() works great!

Comment: I wish i could understand what is being 'prevented', and why it works...

Comment: I updated my answer with some speculation as to what is happening. An interesting topic indeed. Looks like there may be several possible solutions. Hope that helps!